# How to properly deploy a Vue + Apollo Server & Client app on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, vue.js, graphql, vue-cli-3, vue-apollo

I am new and have just been trying out Vue.js with Graphql. After some learning, I went and scaffold a project with vue ui(vue cli 3), added vue-cli-plugin-apollo for both the client and server so my current project structure is as follow:

**Project Folder**

```
─┬── apollo-server (server folder)
 ├── node_modules
 ├── public
 ├─┬ src (client folder)
 │ └┬─ assets
 │  ├─ components
 │  ├─ graphql
 │  ├─ views
 │  ├─ App.vue
 │  ├─ main.js
 │  ├─ router.js
 │  ├─ store.js
 │  └─ vue-apollo.js
 ├── .env
 ├── package.json
 └── vue.config.js
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vue-apollo-graphql",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "apollo": "vue-cli-service apollo:watch --run \"vue-cli-service serve\"",
    "apollo:run": "vue-cli-service apollo:run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql-import": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.2.1",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "merge-graphql-schemas": "^1.5.8",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-graphql": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

On local development, `npm run apollo` works for the the app in localhost:8080(client) & localhost:4000/graphql

**So my question is**: How do I deploy them together on heroku? I have tried searching through the web and information are fragmented and don't make much sense to me. Can anyone give a clearer direction to help me tackle this problem so I can learn and understand more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue, and this is how I've managed it to work.

1. Go to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/server.html#middleware and see the section "Middleware". They say that you can add an Apollo Server as a middleware to existing Express server. So, you should install the package `apollo-server-express` and import ApolloServer from it. Then start your Express server and Apollo Server will be on `path-to-your-server/graphql`.
2. Then you should build your Vue app and specify your path to GraphQL server as a link to your Heroku app plus `/graphql` (I did it through `.env` file).
3. Deploy to Heroku and that's all! It took me around 10 minutes.

Also, you can see my source code here
https://github.com/kravchenkoegor/fullstack-vue-graphql/blob/master/src/server.js